# An extra battery in a hand luggage?

Tags: hand-luggage, power, prohibited-items

I normally carry an extra battery for my electronics. 
I am travelling in Europe.

Is it allowed to have an extra battery in a hand luggage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Probably**, but **with care**

Although the EU security regulations don't prohibit spare batteries, there are separate safety restrictions. [IATA regulations](http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/dgr/Documents/LithiumBattery_PassengerFlyer.jpg) state that:

- Spare batteries < 100Wh are permitted in cabin baggage, but not in the hold.
- You can only carry two spare batteries between 100-160 Wh, again only in the cabin.
- Batteries over 160Wh are not permitted.

In all cases, each battery must either be in a separate plastic bag, or have its terminals covered to prevent a short circuit.

The [British CAA guidelines](http://www.caa.co.uk/default.aspx?catid=2200&pageid=14501) for example are a little more restrictive, requiring airline approval for anything between 100-160Wh. Not sure whether any EU member states have similarly strict guidelines.

For comparison, a laptop battery is typically less than 100Wh

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, you can**. [There is](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/security/doc/info_travellers_hand_luggage.pdf) the list of prohibited objects in hand luggage according to EU regulations. As batteries are not listed you can carry them without further trouble.

Comment: In fact, you must. Spare lithium batteries are not allowed in checked luggage, only cabin bags